# What does the following set consist of?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am unable to interpret the following equation which is used for Unseeded Region growing method to segment images. Can somebody help me with this :

[image]

What does set S comprise of?

Comment: Is $E_k$ defined somewhere??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first equation under Step $2$ should read:

$$S = \left\{ x : x \notin \bigcup_{i=1}^n C_i \land \exists k : N(x) \cap C_k \ne \varnothing \right\}$$

In natural language, this is giving pixels that don't belong to any cluster (the first condition, before the "and") but which are next to a cluster (that is, there's a pixel that both neighbors $x$ and belongs to a cluster $C_k$).

Comment: Thanks! Sorry i dont hve enough reputation points to upvote the answer.